# Can I view the deleted docs in Solr?

Tags: solr, lucene, solr4

I am doing Partial Document updates in `Solr`. As per this link, [Referred](http://solr.pl/en/2012/07/09/solr-4-0-partial-documents-update/) it says when updating the docs, it deletes the older one and add as a new one in `Solr` internally.

Can I view these deleted docs as I read that it would be soft deleted and not physically evicted? Does this cause to increase memory for 1000 docs between adding and adding then updating?

Pls clarify me on this.

Answer (score 0):

All updates of documents in Solr are the same as delete/adds. Older documents are not removed physically from the index before the index is optimized or the segment files are rewritten because of a merge. The difference is usually not relevant for memory usage, as it's only evident in the segment files stored on disk. There are however certain issues with caches being expired if you have a very heavy update load compared to the read load of the index - and you can tune certain settings to accommodate this (but if you're talking about 1000 documents - there's not going to be any practical differences anyway).

[Luke](https://code.google.com/archive/p/luke/) might be able to show you the details you're looking for in the segment files, or you can [write a small Java application to inspect](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene60/package-summary.html) the parts you're interested in.